How to Open a New Terminal in WSL for Running Commands in a Shell Script
I have a Shell script that I originally wrote for an Ubuntu system with a desktop environment. The script makes use of gnome-terminal to open new terminal windows and execute certain commands. Here is the script:
#!/bin/bash 

VPN_USER="name"
CONFIG_FILE="$(pwd)/vpn.ovpn"
 
sudo echo "vpn bağlantısı"

if ifconfig | grep "adress"; then
    gnome-terminal -- bash -c "ssh name@connection_adress"
else
    gnome-terminal -- bash -c "sudo bash -c 'openvpn --config \"$CONFIG_FILE\" --auth-user-pass <(echo -e \"$VPN_USER\n$VPN_PASSWORD\")'"
    sleep 30
    if ifconfig | grep "adress"; then
        gnome-terminal -- bash -c "ssh name@connection_adress"
    else 
        sleep 30
    fi
fi

This script works perfectly on an Ubuntu desktop, but I am now using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which is terminal-only. As a result, the gnome-terminal command does not work in WSL.
Could someone guide me on how to modify this script so that it works correctly in WSL? Specifically, I'm looking for a way to open a new terminal within WSL or to run the equivalent commands without needing a graphical terminal emulator like gnome-terminal.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I initially tried running the script as-is in WSL, hoping that it would open a new terminal or execute the commands in a similar manner to how it worked on Ubuntu with a desktop environment. I expected the script to either open a new terminal window within WSL or run the commands in the current terminal session.
However, since WSL does not support gnome-terminal or any graphical terminal emulator out-of-the-box, the script did not open a new terminal or proceed as expected. Instead, it simply failed at the points where gnome-terminal was invoked, and the associated commands did not execute.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842362/how-to-launch-a-new-wsl-bash-window-from-an-existing-wsl-bash-window
